# Redirect to custom url after checkout completed woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, web, woocommerce

I’m using woocommerce plugin and i want to Redirect to custom url after checkout completed woocommerce and if the purchase is failed nothing happen

Custom code for php theme file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default, WooCommerce will redirect users to the Thank You page after purchase.

If you want to dynamically change the URL a user will be redirected to you can use the *woocommerce_thankyou* action hook.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'kayart_thank_you_page_redirect', 10, 1 );
function kayart_thank_you_page_redirect( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $url = 'https://example.com/';

    if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}
```